# What do the different mysql apt packages do

Tags: mysql, apt

I'm working on a mysql installation script for our system, to be part of an automated deployment system.  Looking through previous installations, it seems like we might have been loading redundant packages, some via apt some via pip.  Looking at Ansible roles for mysql also reveals slightly differing default package lists (e.g. [this](https://github.com/bennojoy/mysql/blob/master/vars/Debian.yml) and [this](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-mysql/blob/master/vars/Debian.yml)).  So I thought I would look up what these packages actually do---only to find that I couldn't find anything informative.

The definitive list, presumably, is [this one from MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/index.html#repo-qg-apt-available).  However I find descriptions like "MySQL database common files" not very helpful.  Common to what?

So my general question: is there a better summary of what the different packages do?  And if the answer to that is no, then at least can anybody tell me when/why I would want to explicitly install these packages (which were included in my legacy scripts):

- mysql-common
- libmysqlclient20
- libmysqlclient-dev

and in the case of the last two, why I would install one or both of those, vs simply installing mysql-client (the "meta" client installer)?

Comment: I have to say that the complete silence on this question is an interesting observation in its own right.  Suggests that not that many people actually know...